# Calling MS Build in post-build event giving error after build. (Code 5)

Tags: msbuild, visual-studio-2017

Our web apps have a post build event that copies web.config files over depending on the configuration that's being built. I wasn't around when this was created, and no one from back then exists on the team today, but it looks like our CI/Deploy server requires it, so removing it isn't an option.

```
Error The command "
          "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\MSBuild\15.0\Bin\msbuild" "E:\{path}\UI.IX.csproj" /t:Transform /p:Configuration=Debug.Dev;Platform=AnyCPU
          Xcopy E:\{path}\obj\Debug.Dev\Web.Config E:\{path}\. /F /R /Y
          ("E:\{Path}\IX.PostBuild\bin\Debug.Dev\IX.PostBuild.exe" 'E:\{Path}' 'E:\{path}\' Debug.Dev /S /Y /I /D /V /C)" 

exited with code 5. Please verify that you have sufficient rights to run this command.
```

The post-build has 3 steps:

1. run MS Build to update the web.config with the correct config based on configuration management
2. Copy the web.config into the bin/obj directory
3. Run a PostBuild .exe file to copy files from one project to another

We're only seeing this error come up on a handful of computers from a new office, and it's not able to be reproduced.

- Visual Studio is being ran as admin, by an admin
- all commands in the Post-Build event can be ran through a Command Prompt without any error
- removed all but msbuild.exe command from post build - still errors (this is the culprit)

Any thoughts on how to fix this error? I don't have this error on 5 machines, but out of 3 new ones in a new office, 2 have this error.

Update

On further inspection we found out that VS was installed by the local Admin prior to joining the domain. I am not sure if this would cause any issues with permissions, but we are re-installing VS on the domain account that will be running the system to see if that fixes anything.

Comment: This definitely sounds like it's a network/machine permission issue - when you say "run by an admin" do you mean network, local, or both? I'd start with checking user groups and folder permissions.

Comment: Local. Right-click VS -> Run as Admin. User running it is an admins group.

Comment: Check slack, it'll be easier there

Comment: How about the permissions of `IX.PostBuild.exe` on the failed machine? If that .exe only have read  permission, we will get the error "exited with code 5" https://mannysiddiqui.wordpress.com/2013/05/11/nuget-access-is-denied-command-existed-with-code-5/, btw, you can check post-build command line one by one to confirm which command throw the error.

Comment: It's the MSbuild line that is causing the error - we found out why. The Antivirus software wasn't told to exclude the code directory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The cause of this issue was Antivirus software. When it was building antivirus software was scanning the new files that were created, and during this scan, Visual Studio was unable to rewrite the files.

We added the source code folder to a list of excluded folders in the AV software and it builds properly now.